# Semantics of naming a MYSQL timestamp column

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions

I need a MySQL table that represents this data:

- **Feb 12, 5:00pm** - Verdasco VS Monfils
- **Feb 12, 9:25pm** - Sampras VS Hewitt
- **Feb 13, 8:15am** - Nishikori VS Del Potro

I wanted to name the time column *time*, *timestamp*, or *date*, but as you know, those are all reserved keywords. What is the best way to name a time column without purposely sounding cheesy to get around the naming limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is Verdasco VS Monfils? Are they events? Then I would go with `EventDate` or something similar. Try to name it of how you would describe it.

Comment: "Verdasco VS Monfils" is an upcoming tennis matchup. I was going to name the whole table *Events*. All the columns should be understood to be related to the table name, so is duplicating the table name in the column name really the way to go?

Comment: Well, I don't see any problem with that in general. But if you name your table `events`, you could name your column `starttime`. `SELECT starttime FROM events` would absolutely make sense then.

Answer (score 4):

I understand the feeling that a column called `EventDate` in a table called `Events` (which, by all the DB conventions I've ever learned, should be called *Event*... ;)) is redundant, but consider:

You have an `Event` table with a `Date` column and a `Booking` table, whose records represent a customer's booking a seat at an event, also with a `Date` column (which, in this context, refers to the date that the seat *was booked*):

```
SELECT e.Date AS EventDate, b.Date AS BookingDate, [...]
FROM Event e
JOIN Booking b ON b.EventId = e.Id
```

Having to account for the ambiguous column names in every such query is a penalty which may (and *does*, in my opinion) outweigh the supposed redundancy of `Event.EventDate`.

Consider another argument which we can apply to the names of the ID columns in each table: calling the PK in `Event` `EventId` instead of merely `Id` lets us write this JOIN criterion:

```
JOIN Booking b ON b.EventId = e.EventId
```

Which we can see at a glance references the correct columns.

In summary, if we have to make the decision between calling the column `Date` or `EventDate`, the latter has many benefits:

- As @Benjamin Seiller points out, a column should identify the column's meaning, not necessarily its datatype
- Further, what happens when you have a table with three different date fields representing dates relevant to the entity? If you don't name them all based on their *meaning*, you now have to remember which field means what...
- As soon as we wish to query multiple tables, ambiguous column names present problems
- If columns that appear in multiple tables (such as foreign keys) have explicit and identical names, our query syntax becomes a little more resistant to bugs (such as joining on the wrong column)

Consider all the situations in which your table may be used when deciding on column names. In this case, I'll argue that the benefits of supplying context-specific information in the column name far outweigh the redundancy of repeating the table name.

Comment: "Event" could be a bit too generic IMHO.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that "Event" is a fabulous name for a table, but the OP did say he wanted to name the table 'Events', so that's the example I used.

Answer (score 2):

The column-name should not point to the data-type but to its meaning.
Like `event_start_datetime` or `created` for the timestamp of creation of that entry.

Comment: I would like to name it *start*, but that's also a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer verb in past tense and "Time", i.e. 'createdTime', 'publishedTime', in your case I can't find a verb, but 'matchTime' looks ok.

Comment: For what it's worth, `MatchTime` was my first thought as well.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL uses the backtick as its identifier delimiter. If you wrap an identifier in backticks, you can use a reserved keyword ([or even spaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)) in an identifier name:

```sql
SELECT `timestamp` FROM  `tennis matches`;
```

Just don't forget to always use backticks for those (or all) identifiers afterwards.